# instead of insert data to 3 table, only the first table get the newly inserted datas ($add_lakas), why?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="hu">
<title>ADD R.E.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>


<form action="Add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**JUST A BIG TABLE FOR INSERT ALL MY DATA FOR THE DB_TABLES**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Alap terület(m^2):</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="area_title"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ár(Ft):</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ar_title"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Város:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="varos_title"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cím(xy utca házszám):</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cim_title"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ház/társasház/sorház:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="tipus1_title"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>tégla/panel/más:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="tipus2_title"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Erkély(van=1;nincs=0):</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="erkely_title"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Lift(van=1;nincs=0):</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lift_title"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Emelet:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="emelet_title"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Szobák száma:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="szobanum_title"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Név:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="nev_title"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Kor:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="kor_title"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Telefon:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="telefon_title"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="click" value="betölt"></td>
</tr>

 </table>
```

**   Table ends **

```
</form>

 </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

**        PHP       **

```
echo $Terulet=$_POST['area_title'];
$Ar=$_POST['ar_title'];
$Varos=$_POST['varos_title'];
$Cim=$_POST['cim_title'];
$Tipus1=$_POST['tipus1_title'];
$Tipus2=$_POST['tipus2_title'];
$Erkely=$_POST['erkely_title'];
$Lift=$_POST['lift_title'];
$Emelet=$_POST['emelet_title'];
$SzobaNum=$_POST['szobanum_title'];
$Nev=$_POST['nev_title'];
$Kor=$_POST['kor_title'];
$telefon=$_POST['telefon_title'];

if($Terulet=='' OR $Ar=='' OR  $Varos=='' OR 
$Cim=='' OR  $Tipus1=='' OR $Tipus2=='' OR 
$Erkely=='' OR  $Lift=='' OR  $Emelet=='' OR 
$SzobaNum=='' OR  $Nev=='' OR  $Kor=='' OR 
$telefon==''){

echo "<script>alert('Fill out all fields!')</script>";
exit();
}
```

**this is what i dont understand how it works:**

```
    else
    {
    $add_lakas="insert into lakas                                    (Terulet,Ar,Varos,Cim,Tipus1,Tipus2,Erkely,Lift,Emelet,SzobaNum)
values ('$Terulet','$Ar','$Varos','$Cim','$Tipus1','$Tipus2','$Erkely','$Lift','$Emelet','$SzobaNum')";

    $run_lakas = mysql_query($add_lakas);

    mysql_free_result($run_lakas);

    $add_elado="insert into elado (Nev,Kor,telefon) values  ('$Nev','$Kor','$telefon')";

    $run_elado = mysql_query($add_elado);

    mysql_free_result($run_elado);

    $add_eladas="insert into eladas (Tulajdonos_telefon) values ('$telefon')";

    $run_eladas = mysql_query($add_eladas);

    if($run_eladas )
    {
    echo "<script>alert('upload done!')</script>";

    echo "<script>window.open('Add.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    mysql_free_result($run_eladas);
    }
    }
    ?>
```

**   I see new rows in phpmyadmin whitin table lakas, but only there**

Comment: How can I do insert all the data to all 3 table with mysql_query?

Answer (score 0):

try n debug your code with

```
$run_lakas = mysql_query($add_lakas)   or die('Invalid query: <br/>'.$add_lakas.'  <br/>' . mysql_error());


$run_elado = mysql_query($add_elado)   or die('Invalid query: <br/>'.$add_elado.'  <br/>' . mysql_error());


$run_eladas = mysql_query($add_eladas) or die('Invalid query: <br/>'.$add_eladas.' <br/>' . mysql_error());
```

Please be informed that mysql functions are deprecated and not recommended. USE MySQLi or PDO instead. have a reference from following queries.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php